# TV screen turns off/flickers when connected to computer through HDMI

Tags: video, display, hdmi, power, tv

My computer is connected to three displays:

- Cable: DVI - Display: 27" computer monitor
- Cable: DVI-HDMI - Display: 24" TV
- Cable: HDMI - Display: 50" TV (routed through an Onkyo 5.1 surround sound system first)

The first two displays are fine, I never have any problems with them but the 50" TV gives me problems all the time. The main one is that it flickers on and off all the time.

When it first started happening it would happen when I'd hear a click across the room that I'd soon find out was coming from a mini-fridge in the room. But now it also happens if I try to display a page that's too bright.

My first thought was that it was being caused by the TV not getting enough power but I quickly ruled that out. It doesn't happen on anything else connected to the TV, only the computer. It's also not the HDMI port on the TV because it happens regardless of what port the computer is connected to.

My second thought was that it was caused by the sound system but that was easily ruled out by connecting the HDMI cable directly to the TV and the problem persisted.

That lead me to thinking it's the computer either not getting enough power or suffering side effects due to voltage fluctuations. So, I bought a Voltage Regulator to connect my PC to. Now the problem seems to happen less but it still happens pretty often and the screen just very recently started turning off if I try to display a page that's too bright on it.

I'm at a loss on what I should try next, I feel like I've tested everything. Could it be the computers power supply or graphics card? If so, how could they be affected by the fridge when it's on a different circuit and connected to a UPS and the computer is also on a UPS/Voltage Regulator?

Comment: It sounds like a power issue. The mini-fridge clicking is probably when it turns on the compressor, increasing it's draw on your supply. As for displaying a bright page? Increasing the backlight brightness could draw more power. Have you tried isolating *just* the computer and TV and testing?

Comment: Yeah I know, as I said I already considered that, that's why the TV is on a UPS and the computer is on a UPS/VR.

However, even if it is a power issue that doesn't help me, there's nothing in this room I can disconnect.

Comment: I think it's a problem with the GPU suffering from power fluctuations, I'm going to get a different GPU and do some tests this weekend.